# Implementing elements of a vector of type class

Tags: c++, class, math, vector

I'm using a class 'triangle' which is expressed as a vector of type 'vertex', 'vertex' being a structure consisting of an x and y value. I have a member function in 'triangle' that is supposed to return the area using heron's formula. Everything works fine until I try to output the area in the main function. Here is my code

vertex.h file

```
#ifndef VERTEX_H
#define VERTEX_H

#include <iostream>

struct vertex
{
    double x, y;

    vertex(double ix = 0.0, double iy = 0.0)
    {
        x = ix;
        y = iy;
    }
};

#endif // VERTEX_H
```

triangle.h file

```
#ifndef TRIANGLE_H
#define TRIANGLE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "vertex.h"

class triangle
{
public:
    triangle(vertex iv0 = vertex(), vertex iv1 = vertex(), vertex iv2 = vertex());
    // pre:
    // post: empty triangle

    triangle(const triangle & source);
    // pre:
    // post: triangle created and initialized to given triangle source

    vertex operator[](size_t i) const;
    // pre: 0 <= i < 3
    // post: return vertex i in this triangle

    double area() const;
    //pre:
    //post: returns area of triangle

private:
    std::vector<vertex> v;
};

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const triangle & p);
std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, triangle & p);
#endif // TRIANGLE.H
```

triangle.cpp file

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include "triangle.h"

triangle::triangle(vertex iv0, vertex iv1, vertex iv2) : v(3)
{
    v[0] = iv0;
    v[1] = iv1;
    v[2] = iv2;
}

triangle::triangle(const triangle &p)
{
    v = p.v;
}

vertex triangle::operator[] (std::size_t i) const
{
    assert(i < v.size());
    return v[i];
}

double triangle::area() const
{
    double a, b, c;
    double s;
    a = sqrt(pow((v[0].x-v[1].x), 2)+pow((v[0].y-v[1].y), 2));
    b = sqrt(pow((v[1].x-v[2].x), 2)+pow((v[1].y-v[2].y), 2));
    c = sqrt(pow((v[2].x-v[0].x), 2)+pow((v[2].y-v[0].y), 2));
    s = (a+b+c)/2;
    return sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
}
//PROBLEM IS HERE^
//(used distance formula to find side lengths a, b, and c)
```

main function

```
#include <iostream>
#include "triangle.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    triangle t;
    t[0] = vertex(2,3);
    t[1] = vertex(5,4);
    t[2] = vertex(3,7);

    cout << t << endl;

    cout << t.area() << endl;

    cout << t.operator [](2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't stated exactly what the problem you're having is. What is going wrong?

Comment: Just for curiosity, why are you using a dynamic data structure when you already know at compile time its size? A `std::array` class exists just for this purpose: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: *Everything works fine until I try to output the area in the main function* ... yet you've left out `main()` and the definitions of `operator<<` and `operator>>`

Comment: when I run the program with cout << t.area << endl; t being a triangle in the main function, it crashes. And this is for a homework assignment which requires that I use a vector

Comment: I would probably declare `triangle::operator[]` to return `vertex &` instead of `vertex`. And not declare it const. Especially if you want to assign to it. (Also both of your constructors should probably be `explicit`.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are initialising your triangle using `operator[]`, you need to make a non-const version of that function that returns a reference.  Generally you return a const reference from the const version too, rather than by value:

```
const vertex& triangle::operator[] (std::size_t i) const
{
    assert(i < v.size());
    return v[i];
}

vertex& triangle::operator[] (std::size_t i)
{
    assert(i < v.size());
    return v[i];
}
```

Your compiler really shouldn't have let you get away with the code you posted.  Modifying an **rvalue** should be an error, or at the very least a warning.  Make sure you compile with warnings turned on, and *read them*!

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with how you are initializing the triangle object. Try initializing it this way:

```
int main()
{
    triangle t (vertex(2,3), vertex(5,4), vertex(3,7));

    cout << t.area() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Another less ideal solution would be to make "v" a public member and then assign the values this way:

```
triangle t;
t.v[0] = vertex(2,3);
t.v[1] = vertex(5,4);
t.v[2] = vertex(3,7);
```